# How to set custom links on YouTube channel with YouTube API (V3)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels, youtube-data-api

Does YouTube API(V3) has an endpoint for updating custom links?

Example:FaceBook,Twitter links... at the bottom right-hand corner of a channel banner
https://www.youtube.com/user/RihannaVEVO